# Override field data type

Tags: picklist, fields

Hi I want change standard field. For example in opportunity - Probability field data type is percentage but I want change the data type to pick list so I can add some pick list values in probability field.
How can I implement, Please help me.

Comment: You have Status field for that.

Comment: no I don't  have any status field

Comment: Sorry its Stage. Stage field is a picklist field and based on this, probability get calculated. You can set this calculation in sales process.

Answer (score 0):

You can not change Standard Fields. Create new custom field as per your need.

FYI ===> To Edit Custom Field - go through following Steps:

1. Go to Setup -> Customize -> Opportunities -> Fields click on it
2. Search for your field "XYZ"
3. click on it to open / OR / Click on "Edit" link next to your field in list.
4. once you "edit" your field --- YOU WILL SEE ONE **"Change Field Type" button** on top of the page, click on it
5. Select the new datatype (in your case Picklist) you want, and click on Next......

Comment: This cannot be done for the Standard Fields......

Comment: ohh...sorry...I missed that part ..... You can't ever change anything for the Standard Field. That's why they are called "Standard Field" , You need to Create Custom Field according to your requirements (you can use same Label Name)

Comment: @Nilesh there is no option. there is no option like Change Field type

Comment: @Nilesh Then It shows 2 probability fields, also I am not hide that field in page layouts

Comment: @Rajesh : Thats right for Standard Field , you will NOT find that option. For Custom Fields, its there.

Comment: @Rajesh : You can do add/remove any fields on PageLayout - doesn't matter its Standard or custom

Comment: opportunity-probability % this field is not  moving

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39013/discussion-between-rajesh-and-nilesh-mendhe).